# Airflow operator and dags and properly returning, exposing, and accessing values?

Tags: python, airflow

I need to create a airflow operator that takes a few inputs and returns a string that will be used as an input for another operator that will run next. I'm new to airflow dags and operators and am  confused on how to properly do this. Since I'm building this for people who use airflow and build dags and I'm not an actual airflow user or dag developer I want to get advice on doing it properly. I have created a operator and it returns a token (just a string so hello world operator example works fine). Doing so I see the value in the xcom value for the dag execution. But how would I properly retrieve that value and input it into the next operator? For my example I just called the same operator but in real it will be calling a different operator. I just do not know how to properly code this. Do I just add code to the dag? Does the operator need code added? Or should something else?

Example Dag:

```
import logging
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from custom_operators.hello_world import HelloWorldOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG("hello_world_test",
    description='Testing out a operator',
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args)

get_token = HelloWorldOperator(
    task_id='hello_world_task_1',
    name='My input to generate a token',
    dag=dag
)

token = "My token" # Want this to be the return value from get_token

run_this = HelloWorldOperator(
    task_id='hello_world_task_2',
    name=token,
    dag=dag
)

logging.info("Start")
get_token >> run_this
logging.info("End")
```

Hello World operator:

```
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator

class HelloWorldOperator(BaseOperator):

    def __init__(
            self,
            some_input: str,
            **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.some_input = some_input

    def execute(self, context):
        # Bunch of business logic
        token = "MyGeneratedToken"
        return token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good start :).

The right way to retrieve the token from another task is to use jinja templating

```
run_this = RetrieveToken(
    task_id='hello_world_task_2',
    retrieved_token="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=[\'hello_world_task_1\']) }}'",
    dag=dag
)
```

However, you have to remember in your RetrieveToken to add `retrieved_token` to `template_fields` array:  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#templating

You can also call `xcom_pull` method explicitly in your "retrieve" operator and pass the "origin" task id to the operator to retrieve it from the right task.